# Display the descriptive status of choices field

Tags: django

I created such a data model of UserProfile:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
        (1,  'male'),
        (0,  'lady'),
    )
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    gender = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=1)
```

The template is expected to show the descriptive gender:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 text-right"><span>Gender:</span></div>
    <div class="col-md-8 text-left"><span>{{ user_profile.gender }}</span></div>
</div>
```

However, it shows

```
Gender: 1 rather than Gender:male
```

How could enable the template to display the descriptive gender?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{{ user_profile.get_gender_display }}`

See [Model.get_FOO_display()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display)